# RESIZING REPORTS IN OBIEE 12C

Tags: oracle, obiee

I am new to OBIEE but I have had cosiderable experience working with oracle reports. I loved the dynamism of oracle reports because I could play with the page heights and width as I wished. However, I have run into an obstacle with OBIEE in that the items are squeezed to fit the width of the report depending on the layout chosen. Is there a way to bypass the default size ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you're using OBIEE then you're using analyses,not reports. If you're really using report and want something reminiscent of Oracle Reports it's rather BI Publisher. Its a separate tool and technology but it comes integrated with OBIEE. That said OBIEE is analytics. BI Publisher is pixel-perfect reporting. Huge difference.